# Get distance between Google Maps markers in pixels or "visual distance"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a way to calculate how close or far away markers are *visually* with Google Maps. I don't care about the mi/km between them. I want to know when, for example, two markers are close to each other as you zoom in.

I know of MarkerClusterer very well. I even have my own heavily modified fork of it but it's not setup the way I need for this project. MarkerClusterer creates an overlay layer which won't work with what I need. This is what I keep seeing suggested to others in other questions.

In my perfect world I'd have a function `distanceInPx` I could use like this:

```
if (distanceInPx(marker1, marker2) < 10) {
  // do my thing
}
```

Or, if there's another way to do this same thing conceptually that would work too.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem, what are you trying to achieve? Looks like you're trying to see if two markers are close to each other, why can't you do this with km and/or miles?

Comment: the km/mi dont change as you zoom in or out. If I zoom way out and something is 10km away they would be overlapping but if I zoom super far in they could be on totally different sides of the screen

Comment: re: "what are you trying to achieve" Im trying to change up some UI when markers are close together visually. As I zoom out they would be in a pie chart if they are very close together. If I zoomed in they'd break apart if there was enough visual distance between them. This is something I can get working for the most part with MarkerClusterer but unfortunately the overlayview makes it a no go for many other features I need to add to it

Comment: Based on the zoom level you can find out what the meters/pixel ratio is (scale). Then you'll have to find out the km distance between the two markers, convert it to pixels with the meter/pixel ratio and you're done.

Comment: ah... yea. so 10mi / zoom of 2 vs 10mi / zoom of 3 or whatever. Thanks!

Comment: If the distance is smaller than ... then what?  Do you still want to cluster these markers?

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay essentially, yes. I mentioned details in the 3rd comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the following function to get distance in pixels between two markers. It supposes that map is initialized, you have global variable `map` and you execute the function after `projection_changed` event is triggered

```
function distanceInPx(marker1, marker2) {
    var p1 = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker1.getPosition());
    var p2 = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker2.getPosition());

    var pixelSize = Math.pow(2, -map.getZoom());

    var d = Math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x) + (p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y))/pixelSize;

    return d;
}
```

Please refer to the documentation for further details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Projection

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Point

**Sample code**

```js
var map;
      
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: 41.079351, lng: -0.758057};

  var madrid = {lat: 40.416775, lng: -3.70379};
  var barca = {lat: 41.385064, lng: 2.173403};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    gestureHandling: "greedy"
  });

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: madrid,
    map: map,
    title: 'Madrid'
  });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: barca,
    map: map,
    title: 'Barcelona'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "projection_changed", function(){
      var d = distanceInPx(marker1, marker2);
      document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = "Distance: " + d;
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function(){
      var d = distanceInPx(marker1, marker2);
      document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = "Distance: " + d;
  });
}

function distanceInPx(marker1, marker2) {
  var p1 = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker1.getPosition());
  var p2 = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker2.getPosition());

  var pixelSize = Math.pow(2, -map.getZoom());

  var d = Math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x) + (p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y))/pixelSize;

  return d;
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="distance"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Hope this helps!